# Regex change date format in yahoo pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I have this format mm/dd/yyyy.
and I need this format dd/mm/yyyy.
I tried with this

```
(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})
```

Change with:

```
$2/$1/$3
```

I use Yahoo pipes with the Regex Module, but don't work.

Comment: String is same as before replace!

Comment: What about yahoo pipes Date module if you want to change the date format ?

Comment: because don't accept the input from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:     `/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/`   as regex.
And use   `"$2/$1/$3"` as replacing string .

Comment: @Sujith PS It seems from your answer that "/" has a meaning in yahoo pipes regex, can you elaborate ?

Comment: @hpchavaz : As of I know , "/" is a notation to denote it is a regular expression ( as in javascript ) . The regex must be in between 2 "/" s.

Comment: @SujithPS thanks for the clarification.
In some other contexts, yahoo pipes for instance, you do NOT use the '/'.